# java Dynamic class loading

Tags: java, reflection, static

When loading the class, using method `forName()`, any static `initializers` in the class are executed.
Can I prevent this ?

```
try {
        Class.forName("MYClass");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass{

static String TEST="MYCLASS";
static SomeClass sm=new SomeClass();
}
```

I found in [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) that there is a overloaded version of Class.forName() i.e.

```
public static Class<?> forName(String name,
                           boolean initialize,
                           ClassLoader loader)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException
```

What is `initialize` parameter ?

Comment: No <!------------------>

Comment: Just remove the `static` keyword!

Comment: Nope.. Could you explain why you even need that.

Comment: Static initializers aren't execute until you actually access one of them. Then and only then it will create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to execute static initialization try class literal instead of Class.forName

```
class A1{
    static{
        System.out.println("static block from A1");
    }
}

class B1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
//      Class.forName("A1");//this will invoke static initialization
        Class c=A1.class;//this will not invoke static initialization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Java creates objects, so no.  One way would be to lazy load the instances at some other time.

This would imply you would have to remove the static reference.

e.g.

```
public SomeClass getSomeClass() {
   if (sm == null) {
      return new SomeClass();
   }

   return sm;

}
```